# Spatial graphs on a torus

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to create a spatial random graph on the torus, so I want to identify the opposite sides of the square.

Can I specify what distance function `SpatialGraphDistribution` uses or I need to do everything manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** A previous implementation of the `DistanceFunction` was just wrong. I tested the current version only a bit, so it may be broken, too. Better use Szabolcs' implementation in IGraph/M; Szabolcs has definitely invested more thinking into it than I.

This might do it:

```
distro = SpatialGraphDistribution[20, 30,
   DistanceFunction -> (
     With[{shifts = Tuples[Transpose[{{0., 0.}, N@Sign[#1 - 0.5]}]]},
       Min[Norm /@ (shifts + ConstantArray[#2 - #1, Length[shifts]])]
       ] &
     )];

ef[p_List, e_] := Module[{shifts},
   shifts = Tuples[Transpose[{{0., 0.}, N@Sign[p[[1]] - 0.5]}]];
   Switch[
    Ordering[Norm /@ (shifts + ConstantArray[p[[2]] - p[[1]], Length[shifts]]), 1][[1]],
    1, Line[p],
    2, {Line[{p[[1]], p[[2]] + shifts[[2]]}], Line[{p[[2]], p[[1]] - shifts[[2]]}]},
    3, {Line[{p[[1]], p[[2]] + shifts[[3]]}], Line[{p[[2]], p[[1]] - shifts[[3]]}]},
    4, {
     Line[{p[[1]], p[[2]] + shifts[[4]]}],
     Line[{p[[1]] - shifts[[4]], p[[2]]}],
     Line[{p[[1]] - shifts[[3]], p[[2]] + shifts[[2]]}],
     Line[{p[[1]] - shifts[[2]], p[[2]] + shifts[[3]]}]
     }
    ]
   ];

G = RandomGraph[distro,
   EdgeShapeFunction -> ef,
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
   PlotRangePadding -> None,
   Frame -> False
   ];
plot = GraphicsGrid[
  ConstantArray[Show[G], {3, 3}],
  Spacings -> 0,
  Frame -> All,
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.5]]
  ]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Szabolcs Maybe the `EdgeShapeFunction` that I've just created is of interest to you...

Answer (score 6):

`IGGeometricGame` in [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has the `"Periodic"` option.  Set it to `True` to use periodic boundary conditions, i.e. a toroidal topology.

The following example is from the documentation. The dashed lines show the "wraparound" edges.

```
IGGeometricGame[50, 0.2, "Periodic" -> True, Frame -> True] // 
 IGEdgeMap[
  If[EuclideanDistance @@ # > 0.2, Dashed, None] &, 
  EdgeStyle -> IGEdgeVertexProp[VertexCoordinates]
 ]
```

[image]